# How to fixed this foreach loop to match to index

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using firebase storage bucket to save files and save their download link to database.

All should should work well, except that the file index are mixed up after I do a foreach loop(_lodash).

```
getFiles(e){
  this.outPutFiles = e;
    _.each(this.outPutFiles, ((file) => {
      const ref = this._storage.ref(file);
      return  ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => this.img_array.push(url));
    }));
}
```

Expected behavior should be:

```
this.outPutFiles = [
0:"o-t-status-files/.....Qd5bGm"
1:"o-t-status-files/.....dz2bd8"
]
```

And the

```
this.img_array = [
0:"https://firebase....%2FJ6Qx9........Qd5bGm"
1:"https://firebase....%2FJ6Qx9........dz2bd8"
]
```

Unfortunately sometimes the file index in the this.img_array doesn't match the file at index on the this.outPutFiles variable.

For instance, the this.img_array may become something like this...

```
this.img_array = [
    0:"https://firebase....%2FJ6Qx9........dz2bd8"
    1:"https://firebase....%2FJ6Qx9........Qd5bGm"
    ]
```

The file at index 0 moved to index 1 and the file at index 1 moved to index 0.

How can I prevent this, to make sure the files index match in both the `this.outPutFiles` and `this.img_array` arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Cause `ref.getDownloadURL()` is async, so the `outPutFiles[1].getDownloadURL()` may finish prior `outPutFiles[0].getDownloadURL()`.

Try something like this (or using rxjs operators):

```
Promise.all(_.map(this.outPutFiles, file => this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL()))
  .then(img_array => console.log(img_array))
```

Comment: ```Promise.all(_.map(this.outPutFiles, file => this._storage.ref(file).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => this.img_array.push(url))));``` gives me the same result. And you are right. I should do an async instead

Comment: No, I did not invoke `subscribe` function!